# How to prevent images from being cropped

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create an animated picture which contains a lot of layers. 
In order to have images with right proportions on different screens I use `cover` css property value(I've tried it for both `object-fit` for images and `background-size` for background images). That's why my images on wide screen are croped by the browser.

The problem is that my layers are transformed(mostly rotated and moved) during the animation so there are moments when it is seen the cropped image.

Please see my example below.

How it can be prevented? Or it there some other technique?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*Just to imitate wide screen*/
  width: 1000px;
  height: 450px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*Just to imitate wide screen*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.layer {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}

.layer img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gulls {  
  animation: gulls ease-in-out 13s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes gulls {
  from {
    transform: rotate(3deg) scaleX(0.95) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-3deg) scaleX(1.05) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="layer">
    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wedding-42174.appspot.com/o/animation%2Fsky.png?alt=media&token=25033588-d58c-4616-94e9-4974ec4157a4" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="layer gulls">
    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wedding-42174.appspot.com/o/animation%2Fgulls5.png?alt=media" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/c08qdw1m/

Comment: Your images are already cropped even without transform, so neither the transform nor the animation are actually related to your issue. In your position, I would rethink the whole thing, unto the image production, even though I'm not sure what should be the best way here. But if you want a quick fix, you might want to play with [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) property.

Comment: You can't cover any screen size without one of the two: cropping or distorting. Here's a decent take: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4jedtb3n/. Methinks.

Answer (score 4):

first of all i have to say that your birds image is a lot bigger then the birds therself (many padding around) as i see the whole image is 2048/1934...

anyway, when you use

```
object fit:cover he crop;
```

the image for save the proportion.  you can using

```
object-fit:scale-down;
```

for save the proportion by scale down the image until he come inside the parent space. i add a quick exemple about how it works down here:

[image]

hope it is what you search for..

Answer (score 2):

Images can be cropped with a container div with `overflow: hidden; position: relative`, So you can position the image inside with `position: absolute`. The `top` and `left` css attribute of the image has to be set a negative value.

The image exact values can be found by using sine and cosine functions.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*Just to imitate wide screen*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*Just to imitate wide screen*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.layer {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}

.layer img {
  height: 150%;
  width: 150%;
}

.gulls {  
  animation: gulls ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes gulls {
  from {
    transform: rotate(3deg) scaleX(0.95) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-3deg) scaleX(1.05) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="layer gulls">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/000000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `overflow: hidden; position: relative` to crop your images after using container div, and using `position: absolute` at the images to place the image.