# How can I prevent my images from being cropped out?

Tags: css, css-grid

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.project');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const overlayImage = document.querySelector('.overlay__inner img');

function open(e) {
  overlay.classList.add('open');
  const src= e.currentTarget.querySelector('img').src;
  overlayImage.src = src;
}

function close() {
  overlay.classList.remove('open');
}

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', open));
overlay.addEventListener('click', close);
```

[Image of lightbox when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwZWJ.jpg)
When I click the view more button my it's not rendering the whole image instead my images are automatically getting cropped out. How can I solve this? I have tried background size: contain, cover & reducing height & width too but nothing worked. thank you so much for helping out.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Merriweather");
body {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  background: #f2dad7;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
}
.project p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.project:hover .grid__overlay {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.grid__overlay {
  background: rgba(48, 40, 39, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(101%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid__overlay button {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid__overlay button:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #d1a39e;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(71, 69, 69, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.overlay.open {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;

  object-fit: none;
  width: 100%;

  padding-right: 500px;
}
.overlay.open img {
  display: block;

  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.overlay__inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #f7f1f1;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.close:hover {
  color: #d1a39e;
}

.project__image {
  margin-left: -25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/austin-lowman-SpSVyLVB_5g-unsplash.jpg" />
      <p>Mazda 3</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/pexels-jonathan-cooper-9763014.jpg" />
      <p>Toyota Supra</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/vehicle-g4435c5dbc_1920.jpg" />
      <p>BMW M5</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/talia-BHlpqQMWDSc-unsplash.jpg" />
      <p>Maserati Ghibli</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/range-rover-gdc459d314_1920.jpg" />
      <p>Range Rover</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/cla-45-amg-a45-amg-45_1600x0.webp" />
      <p>AMG A45s</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/dima-panyukov-a88SUqMaF6k-unsplash.jpg" />
      <p>Porsche 911</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="Images/pexels-grégory-costa-5733730.jpg" />
      <p>Audi R8</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay__inner">
        <button class="close">close X</button>
        <img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010631/how-to-prevent-images-from-being-cropped) help yor?

Comment: Nope it didn't.

Comment: Could you enhance your snippet so that the click works as at the moment we can't see what it does.

Comment: I have added the js code snippet for the click as u asked.

Comment: so you want to make that image fit screen?

Answer (score 1):

I edited some classes in your CSS file.

[here](https://www.diffchecker.com/w6r3kV2y) is the difference.
here is the result.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.project');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const overlayImage = document.querySelector('.overlay__inner img');

function open(e) {
  overlay.classList.add('open');
  const src= e.currentTarget.querySelector('img').src;
  overlayImage.src = src;
}

function close() {
  overlay.classList.remove('open');
}

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', open));
overlay.addEventListener('click', close);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Merriweather");
body {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  background: #f2dad7;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.project img {
  position: absolute;
  width:300%;
}
.project p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  
/*   just to make text more readable */
  background-color:#ffffff80;
  font-size:20px;
}

.project:hover .grid__overlay {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.grid__overlay {
  background: rgba(48, 40, 39, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(101%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid__overlay button {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid__overlay button:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #d1a39e;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(71, 69, 69, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.overlay.open {
  display: block;
}
.overlay.open img {
  display: block;
  margin:auto; /*align center*/
  max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.overlay__inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex; /*align vertical center*/
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #f7f1f1;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.close:hover {
  color: #d1a39e;
}

.project__image {
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/9MxRH8I.jpeg" />
      <p>Range Rover</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/KkAfQv7.jpeg" />
      <p>Mazda 3</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/bTIbBnY.jpeg" />
      <p>Toyota Supra</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/2raW3hE.jpeg" />
      <p>BMW M5</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/HGJaWYO.jpeg" />
      <p>Maserati Ghibli</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/nWA8edA.jpeg" />
      <p>AMG A45s</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zhAEhTC.jpeg" />
      <p>Porsche 911</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/uSBW1Pg.jpeg" />
      <p>Audi R8</p>
      
      <div class="grid__overlay">
        <button class="viewbutton">view more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay__inner">
        <button class="close">close X</button>
        <img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```